# How to change data in ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, addition, observablecollection

How would I be able to change the data in my ObservableCollection without adding or using `add` to my collection?

```
var items = await service.GetTrucksAsync();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    MyCollection.Add(new TruckItems
    {
        TruckId = item.TruckId,
        TruckQuoteId = item.QuoteId,
        TruckPhaseId = item.CurrentPhaseId,
        TruckChassisManufacturer = item.ChassisManufacturer,
        TruckChassisModel = item.ChassisModel,
        TruckStatus = item.Status,
        TruckJobNumber = item.JobNumbers,
        TruckAddedBy = item.AddedBy,
        TruckClientName = item.ClientName,
        TruckClientSurname = item.ClientSurname,
        TruckClientDetail = item.ClientDetail,
        TruckCurrentPhase = item.CurrentPhase
    });
}
dgViewProjects.ItemsSource = MyCollection;
```

I do not want to clear the collection and the add data again, as it causes my datagrid's UI to 'flicker' (clear and load new data again). I need it to be smooth as hell. :)

EDIT: INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented in my class

```
public class TruckItems : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `TruckItems` class needs to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

For example:

```
public class TruckItems : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _truckQuoteId;

    public int TruckQuoteId
    {
        get { return _truckQuoteId; }
        set
        {
            if(value != _truckQuoteId)
            {
                value = _truckQuoteId;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TruckQuoteId));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

---

If you're unable to alter the `TruckItems` class (DAL), you need to create a new class and copy the properties. (for example using a `Mapper`)

---

update:

The problem you are facing is, that you're creating a new instance of `TruckItems`.

```
var items = await service.GetTrucksAsync();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var truckItem = MyCollection.FirstOrDefault(i => i.TruckId == item.TruckId);

    bool isNew = false;

    if(truckItem == null)
    {
        truckItem = new TruckItems();
        isNew = true;
    }

    truckItem.TruckId = item.TruckId;
    truckItem.TruckQuoteId = item.QuoteId;
    truckItem.TruckPhaseId = item.CurrentPhaseId;
    truckItem.TruckChassisManufacturer = item.ChassisManufacturer;
    truckItem.TruckChassisModel = item.ChassisModel;
    truckItem.TruckStatus = item.Status;
    truckItem.TruckJobNumber = item.JobNumbers;
    truckItem.TruckAddedBy = item.AddedBy;
    truckItem.TruckClientName = item.ClientName;
    truckItem.TruckClientSurname = item.ClientSurname;
    truckItem.TruckClientDetail = item.ClientDetail;
    truckItem.TruckCurrentPhase = item.CurrentPhase;

    if(isNew )
       MyCollection.Add(truckItem);

}
```

Comment: It already is. Please view my EDIT. I do not know how to replace my existing data without using the `Add` function.

Comment: An error occurred submitting the edit... $####@##$!@

Comment: Eish that's bad luck!

Comment: If you have loads of data, you could optimize it by creating a lookup `Dictionary<int, TruckItems>` for looking up an `Id` to an `TruckItems` object. But you should only use it, when performance is an issue.

Comment: Thanx for the advice! I will sourly keep it in mind with future problems that I might run into.